# Flutter for loop to generate list of widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have code like this but I want it to iterate over an integer array to display a dynamic amount of children:

```
return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Text(text[0].toString(),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text(text[1].toString(),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Where the `text` variable is a list of integers converted to string here. I tried adding a function to iterate through the array and display the 'children' but was getting a type error. Not sure how to do it since I'm new to Dart and Flutter.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can try this :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> text = [1,2,3,4];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            for ( var i in text ) Text(i.toString())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Note that this was added with the updated of dart to version 2.3. You can read about some of the best changes in [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d)

Another method that was provided before dart 2.3 is this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> text = [1,2,3,4];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(text.length,(index){
            return Text(text[index].toString());
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Weird, I tried the first method and I got an error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 4` with `List<int> text = [1, 2, 3, 4];`

Comment: ah crap my bad, i edited the code to fix it, i used a for each loop. Let me know if you still needed anything!

Comment: It should be `Text(i.toString()` since `i` here is actually the value and not the key.

Comment: This requires 'control-flow-collections' to be enabled

Answer (score 26):

Assuming you want to loop some widgets (e.g Text()) in the Column widget, you can add a loop inside the children property. See a sample below:

```
Column(
   children: <Widget>[
      for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
         Text("Hello" + i)
   ],
)
```

Comment: The i inside the text widget has to be converted to string: Text("Hello" + i.toString())

Comment: Alternatively, you can iterate over a list, like so:   for(final text in texts) Text(text)

Answer (score 16):

You can try .map Method here,

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  List <int> exampleList =  [1,2,3,4];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Container(
        child: Column(
            children: exampleList.map((i) => new Text(i.toString())).toList()
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

This method will come in handy if you have objects inside your list. Also with the **.map()** method **.toList()** must be used at the end.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the map method of your list of Strings.

```
 Widget _getListWidgets(List<String> yourList){
    return Row(children: yourList.map((i) => Text(i)).toList());
  }
```

When your List have a complex Object:

```
Widget _getListWidgets( List<YourObject> lstItens) {
  return Row(children: lstItens.map((i) => Text(i.name)).toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to make use of the [`List.map()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/map.html)

That way you do not have to enable 'control-flow-collections'

```
 Container(
        child: Column(
            children: myList.map((e) => new Text(e)).toList(),
          ),
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> text = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        // better use SizedBox instead of Container
        child: Column(
          // children: text.map((e) => Text("$e")).toList() // OPTION 1
          children: [...text.map((e) => Text("$e"))],       // OPTION 2 using spread operator
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```