# Get data from a nested List<Object> and display it on a widget

Tags: list, flutter, nested-lists

I have a List with this structure called userList

List userLIst = [{NAME: John, SURNAME: Doe, DATE: 24/8/2021, DESCRIPTION: Some words}, {...}, {...}];

I want to refer to that list and use List.generate(userList.length, index) => Container(display data from the list), so I can display all the data inside the cards. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the map method for Lists:

```
final widgetList = userList.map((element) => Container(child: Text(element['NAME']))).toList();
```

than you can display this list in a `ListView` or `Column` Widget in build method.

```
class YourView extends StatelessWidget{

 Widget build(){
  final widgetList = userList.map<Widget>((element) => Container(child: 
    Text(element['NAME']))).toList();

  return ListView(
    children: widgetList,
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. you have to loop through the list generate widgets based on each map data, like this:

```
 for (var i in userLIst)
    Column(children:[
    Text(i.keys)
    Text(i.values),
    ])
```

I used for loop instead of List.generate. refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947046/flutter-for-loop-to-generate-list-of-widgets) for more information.